# I cannot save my contacts after resetting my Nokia lumia 630?

Tags: contacts, windows-10-mobile

I done a reset of my nokia lumia 630 of win10.After completeion of formatting I could not add the new contacts when I click on save button it is redirecting to home page.Please help me.

Comment: By "home page" do you mean the Start screen? Is the People app crashing? Also, is your phone fully up-to-date?

Comment: yes just now I reset my phone and installed the updated but issue with saving the contacts

Comment: people app is crashing

Comment: why don't you give reply.I could not understand.I have severe problem

Comment: Try going to the Store and checking for updates. Also make sure that there isn't an error with your MS account.

Comment: @Mouni I'm sorry, but I don't have a solution for you. I was just trying to help you clarify the problem. Hopefully someone else can offer a solution. Also, please note that we're all volunteers here, this is not an official Microsoft support channel.